# hide actions in lense laravel nova

Tags: laravel, laravel-nova

how to hide actions in the lense page I have following actions in my resource

```
    public function actions(Request $request)
{
    return [
        (new AddNewURL)
            ->canSee(function () use ($request) { return $request->user()->hasPermission('updatedOrders-create');})
            ->canRun(function () use ($request) { return $request->user()->hasPermission('updatedOrders-create');})
            ->withoutConfirmation(),
        (new EditNewURL)
            ->canSee(function () use ($request) { return $request->user()->hasPermission('updatedOrders-update-all');})
            ->canRun(function () use ($request) { return $request->user()->hasPermission('updatedOrders-update-all');})
            ->withoutConfirmation(),
        (new PrintBillings)
            ->withoutConfirmation()
            ->canSee(function () use ($request) { return $request->user()->hasPermission('orders-actions-print');})
            ->canRun(function () use ($request) { return $request->user()->hasPermission('orders-actions-print');}),
        (new DownloadExcel)
            ->onlyOnIndex()
            ->withoutConfirmation(),
    ];
}
```

I want to hide them in the lense page I already tried

```
public function actions(Request $request)
{
    return [];
}
```

in the lense class but didn't work, also I removed the actions method completely yet it doesn't work. also, I tried `->canSee(function () { return false;})` yet it doesn't work !!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the actions that are shown in the table rows can not be overridden, but the actions that are shown in the index top right corner can be overridden by overriding **action** method on the lense.

```
public function actions(Request $request)
{
    return [];
}
```

in this case, all actions that are shown in index will be gone